# global object access across the session in web2py?

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py, cache-control

I'm new to webdev, these days plan for writing a boradgame with web2py.

When start to coding, I found that I can't use global variables easily.

for demo purpose, I want a python list object access by many players, I use *sqlite* to make it work.

the database, (using `DAL('sqlite:memory:')` won't work), so I try the file way, it works as my thought:

```
memdb = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
memdb.define_table('room', Field('card_on_desk', 'blob'))
```

create a room:

```
roomid = memdb.room.insert(card_on_desk=pickle.dumps(list()))
memdb.commit()
```

change the room's card_on_desk field:

```
record = memdb.room(roomid)
cards = pickle.loads(record.card_on_desk)
cards.append(','.join(c))
memdb(memdb.room.id==roomid).update(card_on_desk=pickle.dumps(cards))
memdb.commit()
```

Some gurus said there is a cache.ram() way, I want to know how to do the above stuff.

wait for your answers.

[S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) mention that I did not describe what happens when using DAL('sqlite:memory:'):

using `sqlite:memory` instead of 'sqlite://storage.sqlite', the memdb insert is alright in a http request, but nothing saves, everytime you I call `memdb.room.insert()` returns the times I called and when the request is finish, nothing saved in memory, memdb.room(1) always return None.

[Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440323/anthony)'s advice is more useful, I'll try to use that way, bit hard to do so.

Comment: "but it won't work"?  Since that makes no sense, you'll wait forever for answers.  Perhaps you should explain "but it won't work".

Comment: @S.Lott seems like you misunderstand me, sorry for my bad description. I means `DAL('sqlite:memory:')` won't work, the file way works.

Comment: @Gohan: It seems like you misunderstood me.  Sorry for being vague.  "won't work" doesn't mean anything.  It is meaningless.  It cannot be understood.  You must provide the **actual** error that you're **actually** getting.  A summary ("won't work") is not acceptable.  A fact (an error message, for example) is acceptable.

Comment: Have you looked at the book section on [caching](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#cache) -- it should be fairly straightforward? Also, you don't generally need to call commit() explicitly -- transactions are committed automatically at the end of every request (see [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#commit-and-rollback)).

Comment: @S.Lott update the result in the question using `sqlite:memory`.  @Anthony working on it, but still confuse.

Comment: @Gohan: "but nothing saves"?  That's not actually possible for nothing to save.  First, a ":memory:" database is **temporary**.  Second, why do you think `memdb.room(1)` will find anything? What makes you think the id will be `1`?  It could just as easily be 0 or a random number assigned by SQLite.  The value of `roomid` may not actually be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to persist the information, then you can use the session

```
session.myvariable
```

if you need to persist and you want to speed up things with cache, then you can cache the select:

```
def cache_db_select():
    logs = db().select(db.log.ALL, cache=(cache.ram, 60))
    return dict(logs=logs)
```